# I keep getting a NaN when calculating numbers

Tags: java, nan

Whenever I put the following into a program it always comes back with `NaN`. Does anybody know why? Is there a way I can fix this?

```
double test = -1.17425 * (pow(10, 3)) / (5.75 * (pow(10, 6)));
System.out.print(test);
```

Comment: This runs fine for me: `-2.0421739130434784E-4` (Using `Math.pow`)

Comment: Show us compilable, runnable code that demonstrates the error when you run it.

Comment: http://ideone.com/cwO975 its working for me as well

Comment: Please, post the whole code, including imports.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine on my computer. I get:
`-2.0421739130434784E-4`

Which math library are you using? Try this:
`double test = -1.17425*(Math.pow(10,3))/(5.75*(Math.pow(10,6)));`